# Parse all text in a list before equals sign

Tags: regex, parsing, sed, awk

I want to achieve something like this:

BEFORE:

```
SOME_TEXT=some_more_text
OTHER_TEXT=some_other_text
```

AFTER:

```
SOME_TEXT
OTHER_TEXT
```

I could print using awk or sed with regex and have the equals sign as the field separator.

But what's the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With awk, that would be as simple as:

```
awk -F= '{print $1}' thefile
```

With sed:

```
sed 's,=.*,,' thefile
```

That is provided, your input is a file named `thefile`.

Comment: Thanks fge, really useful. Went with sed.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution which uses "cut".

```
$ cat > /tmp/d.log
SOME_TEXT=some_more_text
OTHER_TEXT=some_other_text
$ cat /tmp/d.log |cut -d"=" -f1
SOME_TEXT
OTHER_TEXT
```

Answer (score 3):

If `File` contains your string. Do this,

```
cut -f1 -d= File
```